# Can variables in inline functions conflict with local variables?

Tags: c, inline

In C, can local variables of an inline function conflict with local variables from the function in which it is called? For example:

```
inline void func1() {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        // Some code
    }
}

void func2() {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        func1();
    }
}
```

Would the iterator in `func1` conflict with the iterator in `func2`?

Comment: I will compile this for you to test and let you know what I find.

Comment: A function is a function is a function is not a macro. Why do you think the `inline` _function specifier_ changes that?

Comment: @SeanBright That's not how you figure out things in C because undefined behaviour.

Comment: Experimentation is exactly how you "figure out things."

Comment: @SeanBright Not in C because things that appear to work just fine can be undefined behaviour. Then you have a bug in your program that you only find when the compiler starts to exploit the undefined behaviour or when the code changes and the undefinedness starts to have an effect on your code.

Comment: So before you wrote your first line of C code, you read the standard?

Comment: @SeanBright: That's not how it works in artificially defined systems with definition gaps like C or C++ and most other programming languages (not sure if there is any turing-complete programming language without one or the other undefined/indeterminate/implementation-specific behaviour).

Comment: @SeanBright Back then I didn't, but I quickly started once I had questions about things that weren't obvious to me.

Comment: @FUZxxl: And you're still not too scared using C ;-)

Comment: @Olaf Just like all religious people, I also have my holy book that gives me peace and solace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `inline` specifier is mostly just a hint to the compiler. It doesn't make the function any different. The variables declared in the function still have block scope and don't interfere with other variables.

Comment: Strictly speaking the variables have block-scope, starting from their definition, as all local variables. It just happens the block they are declared in is also the the function body. Things are a bit more complicated with `for` loops, otherwise the rules are very straight forward.

Comment: If your `inline` function definition has global visibility (defined in a header), then "local identifiers of the function (parameters or local variables) may be subject to macro expansion for macros that we don't even know about." (p. 263, Modern C).

But @toohonestforthissite 's comment is the most accurate answer here.

Answer (score -7):

I've compiled this simple test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static inline void func1()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("i from func1(): %d\n", i);
    }
}

static void func2()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        func1();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    func2();
}
```

And after compiling and running, I see the following output:

```
i from func1(): 0
i from func1(): 1
i from func1(): 2
i from func1(): 3
i from func1(): 4
i from func1(): 5
i from func1(): 6
i from func1(): 7
i from func1(): 8
i from func1(): 9
```

Which is repeated 5 times. So it appears that the answer to your question is "no."

Comment: Relying on a specific implementation is not a proof of standard compliance. Why not just have a look at the standard? There is no statement the `inline` specifier is more than a hint to the compiler (basically, it has some additional semantics for declaration vs. definition, but these are not relevant here).

Comment: Downvote: This could be undefined behaviour and appear to work just fine. “I tried, it seems to work” is not how you determine details of the C language.